# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘highest’)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Code:

````
const { EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField } = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");
const ms = require("ms");
const modSchema = require("../../models/modLogs");

module.exports = {
  name: "mute",
  description: "Mutes a user in a server",
  usage: "[name | nickname | mention | ID] (reason)",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    try {
      const usageChannel = message.client.guilds.cache.get("705344500507345017").channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "usage-log");
      await usageChannel.send({ content: `\`${message.author.tag}\` executed the \`mute\` command in **${message.guild.name}**.` }).catch(() => null);

      if (!message.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageRoles)) return message.reply('You do not have perms to use this command. - `[MANAGE_ROLES]`')
      if (!message.guild.members.me.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageRoles)) return message.reply('I do not have perms to exexute this command. - `[MANAGE_ROLES]`');
        
      if (!args[0]) return message.reply("```Usage: c!mute <user>```");
        
      var mutedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.user.username.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.guild.members.cache.find(ro => ro.displayName.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase());
        
      if (!mutedMember) return message.reply("Please provide a valid user to mute.");
      if (mutedMember === message.member) return message.reply("I'm afraid you cannot mute yourself, Captain.");
      if (message.author.roles.highest.position <= mutedMember.roles.highest.position) return message.reply("<a:CL_No:909440866622517318> You cannot mute that user because they have the same or higher role than you.");
````

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘highest’)
```

So I don’t know what ive missed, but I’ve looked in the djs documentation for a change to this, but didn’t find anything to this error unless it’s something else that I didn’t see or missed.

Comment: Either `message.author.roles` or `mutedMember.roles` is undefined. Have you tried debugging`message.author` and `mutedMember` to see what properties they _do_ have?

Comment: No I have not, how would I do that

Comment: Logging is the simplest version... `console.log("message author", JSON.stringify(message.author))` and `console.log("mutedMember", JSON.stringify(mutedMember))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming because you are trying to access the `roles` property on [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) which returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User) property. A [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User) object does not have a `roles` property. Instead, what you are looking for is a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) object. To access that, all you have to do is use [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member). Your fixed code would look like this:

````js
const { EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField } = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");
const ms = require("ms");
const modSchema = require("../../models/modLogs");

module.exports = {
  name: "mute",
  description: "Mutes a user in a server",
  usage: "[name | nickname | mention | ID] (reason)",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    try {
      const usageChannel = message.client.guilds.cache.get("705344500507345017").channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "usage-log");
      await usageChannel.send({ content: `\`${message.author.tag}\` executed the \`mute\` command in **${message.guild.name}**.` }).catch(() => null);

      if (!message.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageRoles)) return message.reply('You do not have perms to use this command. - `[MANAGE_ROLES]`')
      if (!message.guild.members.me.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageRoles)) return message.reply('I do not have perms to exexute this command. - `[MANAGE_ROLES]`');
        
      if (!args[0]) return message.reply("```Usage: c!mute <user>```");
        
      var mutedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.user.username.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.guild.members.cache.find(ro => ro.displayName.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase());
        
      if (!mutedMember) return message.reply("Please provide a valid user to mute.");
      if (mutedMember === message.member) return message.reply("I'm afraid you cannot mute yourself, Captain.");
      if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= mutedMember.roles.highest.position) return message.reply("<a:CL_No:909440866622517318> You cannot mute that user because they have the same or higher role than you.");
````

Note: It's actually a simple problem which is pretty common around here. Please, before you try to post your question, just check around Google or SO, for these kinds of problems and you should find your solution